# ESBJAVA-4807 was said to be fixed in version 5.0.0/5.0.0-RC3 but not

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In ESB version 4.9.0, when using ftp in File Inbound EndPoint, I encountered a known issue described in https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4807 (Error log continuously printing in the carbon log).  ESBJAVA-4807 was reported for sftp and it was said the issue was fixed in version 5.0.0 and 5.0.0-RC3.  However, after downloaded ESB version 5.0.0, I am still experiencing the same behavior.  I am hoping the fix addresses both sftp and ftp.

Does anyone know why?  Did I miss something?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you share your exception? Then we can determine whether its thrown from the same place.

Comment: It looks to me it occurs at the same try/catch block within the finally block. Exception show below

TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-27 12:16:36,146] ERROR
{org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.file.FilePollingConsumer} - Unable to close the file system. null {org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.file.FilePollingConsumer}
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-27 12:16:36,146] ERROR
{org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.file.FilePollingConsumer} - java.lang.NullPointerException {org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.file.FilePollingConsumer}

Answer (score 0):

I decompiled the file and see the changes made by ESBJAVA-4807; however the issue persists.  I had added a comment in the JIRA ticket.